# How to force xticks and yticks on Matplotlib histogram?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I'm trying to set the xticks and sticks in my histogram to a certain range instead of having Matplotlib fit the axes to the data. For example if I have a set of data for which my max frequency (ytick) needs to be 100, I still want yticks to go up to 200.

I have already trued using plt.xticks() and plt.yticks() but Matplotlib tends to fit the graph axes ticks to fit the data.

```
    plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 1, 0.1))
    plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 100,10))
    plt.hist(data['numbers'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to set the x- and y-ticks **after** plotting the histograms. That means, try the following

```
# First plot
plt.hist(data['numbers'])

# Then assign the ticks
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 1, 0.1))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 100,10))
```